# How to sort data using XLSXWRITER in Python?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Currently I want to convert content in txt file to excel file using XLSXWRITER in python. The txt file contains some information with a specific datetime but it is not sorted from the latest date to oldest date. Is there any way to sort it and convert to excel file?

Comment: Do you want to sort first then import or import then sort or import then use excel to sort

Comment: @cup if possible I want to sort first then import so that it is already sorted in excel